# Unrolling a sheet from a hyperboloid of one sheet

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, solid-of-revolution

When a sheet is drawn taut from a cylindrical roll of paper, a flat sheet traveling in a straight line results. When a sheet is drawn from a cone, the paper unfurls out as a flat disk. So, how about unfolding out a sheet from a hyperboloid (that is, a hyperboloid of one sheet, not to confuse by what I mean by "sheet")? To be more precise, what are the parametric equations that define such a surface? In all cases, the shapes from which the sheets are rolled can freely rotate about their axis of revolution.

Since a hyperboloid is a ruled surface, it is possible to draw a sheet from it in the first place without distortion of the sheet, i.e. isometry. One thing I notice is that a hyperboloid has non-zero Gaussian curvature, and so the sheet cannot be unfolded into a plane. So perhaps what it means to unfold out a sheet tautly isn't well defined for non-zero Gaussian curvature scenarios.

This image I found suggests the answer is indeed a helicoid. However it doesn't give away much in the way of parametric equations, or whether this holds for the general case.

[image]

Any help in finding the parametric equations or even the methodology for finding such surfaces would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: As you've observed, you need a surface of constant curvature $0$ for the unrolling (or developing) into a plane to work. But there is another class of flat ruled surfaces, the so-called tangent developables. Take the set of tangent lines to a space curve. These form a ruled surface with a cuspidal edge along the original curve. This surface has none of the symmetry you're taking for granted. I'm not quite sure what's actually happening in this picture.

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article on developable surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface): A hyperboloid is ruled but not developable.

Answer (score 1):

Shall attempt an answer as it appears to me. The *"rollers"* are identical shaped as 1-sheet hyperboloids, both right handed or both left handed.

The rulings that are force squeezed by heavy metal rollers placed opposite each other are asymptotic lines of a stretched helicoid surface of paper or aluminum foil, transferred from generators of  hyperboloid.

A flat sheet is drawn out/rolled out to an (average) shape of a helicoid. If paper sheet is used, there would be corrugations and if thin metal foil is used *plastic deformation* occurs. Lines at the end of ribbon undergo a differential permanent tensile strain. The twisted helicoid that emerges is not isometric to a $K=0$ flat sheet that goes into the rollers.

Parametrization is the usual $ (x,y,z)= (u \cos v, u \sin v , c\, v) $ where $c$ relates to skew angle of the straight generators.

The above is deformation picture in the tangent plane. I suppose the surface shown inside the forming rollers is representation of corresponding normal surface, orthogonal to the deformed tangential surface.